# PHP e Javascript - Enviando anexo HTML em e-mail

Tags: php, javascript, html, envio-de-email

Criei no site do meu cliente uma função que emite um certificado de evento realizado e manda por e-mail. Como está a função no momento:

```
private static function setLayoutCertificado(){
    class_exists('Email') || include_once LIBRARY_CLASS_PATH . 'Email.class.php';

    $assunto = "Certificado de evento externo do colaborador " . $_SESSION['usuario']['nome'];
    $layout  = '<html>
<body>
<div id="folhaA4paisagem">
<div id="logoPrograma" style="text-align: center">
    <img id="imgPrograma" style="width: 400px" src="http://meusite.com.br/protected/viewc/theme/site/img/common/img/logo_quagilidade_original.png" />
</div>
<div id="textoCertificado" style="text-align: center; font-family: Trebuchet MS; font-size: 24px; width: 1000px; position: fixed; top: 40%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); line-height: 1.3;">
    Certificamos que o(a) colaborador(a) '.$_SESSION['usuario']['nome'].' participou da capacitação '.str_replace("'","",$_SESSION['eventoCert']).', com carga-horária de '.str_replace("'","",$_SESSION['cargaCert']).', realizado no dia '.str_replace("'","",$_SESSION['dataCert']).'. 
</div>
<div id="assinaturas" style="text-align: center; font-family: Trebuchet MS; font-size: 10px; width: 1000px; position: fixed; top: 70%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">
    <table id="tableAssinaturas" style="text-align: center; align: center; position: fixed; top: 70%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">
        <tr>
            <td>___________________________________</td>
            <td style="min-width: 300px"></td>
            <td>___________________________________</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nome 1</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Nome 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cargo 1</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Cargo 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="logo" style="text-align: center; width: 1000px; position: fixed; top: 90%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">
    <img src="http://meusite.com.br/protected/viewc/theme/site/img/common/img/logo_grande.png" />
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>';

    $o_email = New Email();
    $o_email->to = 'meuemail@gmail.com';
    $o_email->subject = $assunto;
    $o_email->content = $layout;
    $o_email->sendSmtp(SMTPHOST, SMTPUSER, SMTPPASSWORD);
}
```

O que eu queria fazer era transformar esse código do HTML em um anexo (com extensão HTML mesmo) desse e-mail, pois o que sai no corpo do e-mail não fica muito bom. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Já fiz isso e preciso procurar o código, mas acho que no seu caso é melhor tentar formatar pra ir no e-mail mesmo mesmo porque indo como anexo a maioria das pessoas não vai nem abrir e alguns clientes de e-mail vão aumentar as chances de que seu e-mail seja considerado spam. Em último caso até um link ia ser melhor do que enviar como anexo.

Comment: @AntonioAlexandreAlonsodeSi Até não tem problema pra mim mandar já a formatação no corpo do e-mail ou o código HTML. Mas o problema é que na hora de imprimir o certificado não fica legal ele estando no corpo do e-mail, pelo menos no Gmail. Se tu tiveres o código aí, agradeço.

Comment: Vou pôr numa resposta um exemplo antigaço que eu fiz em 2012 de um envio de e-mail autenticado via smtp com arquivo em anexo. Teste e veja se ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro tem essa classe que fiz com base em umas funções que encontrei na internet em 2012:

**EmailAuthenticator.php**

```
<?
class EmailAuthenticator
{

var $conn;
var $user;
var $pass;
var $debug;
var $boundary;

function __construct($host)
{
    $this->boundary= "XYZ-" . date("dmYis") . "-ZYX";
    $this->conn = fsockopen($host, 25, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    $this->Put("EHLO $host");
}

function Auth()
{
    $this->Put("AUTH LOGIN");
    $this->Put(base64_encode($this->user));
    $this->Put(base64_encode($this->pass));
}

function addFile($corpo_mensagem, $arr_arquivo)
{
    $arquivo_path = $arr_arquivo["path"];
    $arquivo_type = $arr_arquivo["type"];
    $arquivo_name = $arr_arquivo["name"];

    if(file_exists($arquivo_path))
    {
        // Nesta linha abaixo, abrimos o arquivo enviado.
        $fp = fopen($arquivo_path,"rb"); 
        // Agora vamos ler o arquivo aberto na linha anterior
        $anexo = fread($fp,filesize($arquivo_path));            
        // Codificamos os dados com MIME para o e-mail 
        $anexo = base64_encode($anexo);
        // Fechamos o arquivo aberto anteriormente
        fclose($fp); 
        // Nesta linha a seguir, vamos dividir a variável do arquivo em pequenos pedaços para podermos enviar
        $anexo = chunk_split($anexo);
        // Nas linhas abaixo vamos passar os parâmetros de formatação e codificação, juntamente com a inclusão do arquivo anexado no corpo da mensagem.
        $this->msg = "--".$this->boundary."\n"; 
        $this->msg.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bits\n"; 
        $this->msg.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"ISO-8859-1\"\n\n";
        $this->msg.= "$corpo_mensagem\n"; 
        $this->msg.= "--".$this->boundary."\n"; 
        $this->msg.= "Content-Type: ".$arquivo_type."\n";  
        $this->msg.= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$arquivo_name."\"\n";  
        $this->msg.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n";  
        $this->msg.= "$anexo\n";  
        $this->msg.= "--".$this->boundary."--\r\n"; 
    }
}


function Send($to, $from, $subject, $msg, $arr_arquivo=null){
    $this->msg = $msg;

    $this->Auth();
    $this->Put("MAIL FROM: " . $from);
    $this->Put("RCPT TO: " . $to);
    $this->Put("DATA");

    if($arr_arquivo!=null)
    {
        $this->addFile($msg, $arr_arquivo);
        $this->Put($this->toHeaderWithAttachment($to, $from, $subject, $this->boundary));
    }
    else
    {
        $this->Put($this->toHeader($to, $from, $subject));
    }

    $this->Put("\r\n");
    $this->Put($this->msg);
    $this->Put(".");
    $this->Close();
    if(isset($this->conn))
    {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function Put($value)
{
    return fputs($this->conn, $value . "\r\n");
}

function toHeader($to, $from, $subject)
{
    $header  = "Message-Id: <". date('YmdHis').".". md5(microtime()).".". strtoupper($from) ."> \r\n";
    $header .= "From: <" . $from . "> \r\n";
    $header .= "To: <".$to."> \r\n";
    $header .= "Subject: ".$subject." \r\n";
    $header .= "Date: ". date('D, d M Y H:i:s O') ." \r\n";
    $header .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High \r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: Text/HTML";
    return $header;
}

function toHeaderWithAttachment($to, $from, $subject, $boundary){
    $header = "Message-Id: <". date('YmdHis').".". md5(microtime()).".". strtoupper($from) ."> \r\n";
    $header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";  
    $header.= "From: $from\r\n";
    $header.= "To: $to\r\n";
    $header.= "Reply-To: $from\r\n";
    $header.= "Subject: ".$subject." \r\n";
    $header.= "Date: ". date('D, d M Y H:i:s O') ." \r\n";
    $header.= "Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";  
    $header.= "$boundary\n"; 
    return $header;
}

function Close()
{
    $this->Put("QUIT");
    if($this->debug == true)
    {
        while (!feof ($this->conn)) 
        {
            fgets($this->conn) . "<br>\n";
        }
    }
    return fclose($this->conn);
}

}
?>
```

Depois tem esse arquivo aqui que usa a classe:

**envia_autenticado_com_anexo.php**

```
<?
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include ("EmailAuthenticator.php");

$from = "seuemail@seuservidor.com.br";
$to =   "seuemail@seuservidor.com.br";
$subject = "Teste da classe que envia e-mail autenticado com anexo";

// Aqui abaixo, vamos colocar o corpo da mensagem, como vamos utilizar padrão HTML, teremos de utilizar tags HTML abaixo
$corpo_mensagem = "<html>
<head>
   <title>Teste de Envio</title>
</head>
<body>
<font face=\"Arial\" size=\"2\" color=\"#333333\">
<br />
<b>Olá mundo!!</b> <br />
Este é mais um teste da <b>classe</b> que envia e-mail autenticado com anexo.
</font>
</body>
</html>";

$arquivo_path=$_FILES["meuarquivo"]["tmp_name"]; //caminho do arquivo 
$arquivo_name=$_FILES["meuarquivo"]["name"]; //nome correto do arquivo com a extensão correta
$arquivo_type=$_FILES["meuarquivo"]["type"]; //tipo do arquivo

$arr_arquivo = array( "path" => $arquivo_path, 
                      "name" => $arquivo_name,
                      "type" => $arquivo_type );

// Envio Autenticado

$host = "mail.seuservidor.com.br";
$smtp = new EmailAuthenticator($host);
$smtp->user = "seuemail@seuservidor.com.br";            /* usuario do servidor SMTP */
$smtp->pass = "suasenha";                               /* senha do usuario do servidor SMTP */
$smtp->debug =true; 

if( $smtp->Send($to, $from, $subject, $corpo_mensagem, $arr_arquivo) )
{
    echo "ok";
}
else
{
    echo "error";
}
?>
```

E por último tem esse form que faz o post de um arquivo(para testar com qualquer arquivo de forma fácil, mas vc pode depois mudar a parte que chama $_FILES no arquivo acima pra onde tá seu arquivo no servidor):

**form.html**

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="envia_autenticado_com_anexo.php">
        <input type="file" name="meuarquivo" />
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Se este código tiver sido útil, dê uma moral e clique na setinha pra cima pra me dar pontos de reputação. 
Se achar essa resposta adequada e que resolve o seu problema, caso a marque como respondida também estará me dando pontos de reputação.

Valew, falow, abraços. :)

Quaisquer dúvidas poste aqui nos comentários da resposta.